# Xamarin Forms - Set default TextColor

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to set the default text color to a specific color for all the page elements that contain text?

It doesn't make sense to me that I need to set a 'TextColor' attribute for every element that contain text.

Thanks!

Comment: There is not a base class for all visual elements that contains Text property. So you have to create a separate implicit style for each visual element that you want.

Answer (score 10):

You can set the style of the elements containing text in the App.xaml. This will set the TextColor for all Labels, Buttons,... you use in your app:

```
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Entry">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Editor">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
...
```

Unfortunately you will have to add a new Style tag for all Visual Elements containing text. I've been searching for a cleaner way to define styles for all elements with text a while ago. But this seems to be the cleanest way to do it...

Hopefully Xamarin.Forms will add a more generic way to handle the styling.

Comment: Does Xamarin.Forms have an App.xaml..? My project certainly doesn't, and trying to add one only breaks things.

Comment: Yes, your core (shared) project has an App.xaml file. Maybe you're confusing Xamarin.Forms with native Xamarin.Android/Xamarin.iOS projects?

Answer (score 0):

Since Xamarin Forms 2.6.0 you can use CSS styling. That allows you to set styles for elements or specific css classes globally.

Add file `styles.css` to folder `YouProject.Shared > Assets` with following content. (Note the `^` symbol. It selects any element with this base class)

```
^Label {
    color: red;
}

^Entry {
    color: red;
}

^Button {
    color: red;
}
```

Add resource to a global view (e.g. you use `MasterDetailPage`) to load css file:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Resources>
    <StyleSheet Source="/Assets/styles.css" />
</MasterDetailPage.Resources>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but useful.

In `App.xaml` a style for Label with the name `BLabel`.

```
<Style x:Key="BLabel" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor"  Value="#A7ADB1" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Start" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
```

You can use it like this , in `MainPage.xaml`.

```
  <Label
   Grid.Row="4"
   Grid.Column="1"
   Style="{StaticResource BLabel}"
   Text="BB 3" />
```

But there is more you can add to this like:

```
  <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="150" />
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
        <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="TextTransform" Value="None" />
```

and more ....

Not only for labels but buttons etc.

This is an example for `StaticResource` but you can also use `DynamicResource` to change color's etc.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Se0yF5JXk70&ab_channel=JamesMontemagno

Answer (score -2):

You have to create custom-render for Label and Entry or any other control in android and iOS and you can apply colour directly there
`[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(IOSLabelRenderer))]
namespace test
{
    public class IOSLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.TextColor = UIColor.Brown;
        }
    }
}`
you can create same for Android also